# Is there any Event for <p:tooltip>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

I'm using primefaces . In my Screen i have to calculate and  show the remaining days in `<p:tooltip>`  if mouse cursor is in date field. How to do this ? Is there any event for tooltip ?

Comment: how about calculating remaining days on date change and when mouse moves over date, tooltip displays the remaining days

Comment: for that i'm asking any event is thr ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no PrimeFaces events related to `p:tooltip` however you can use Javascrip/jQuery to simulate lazy loading for a `p:tooltip`:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton id="button" value="button" />
    <p:tooltip for="button" id="tooltip">
        <p:outputPanel id="tooltip-content-wrapper">
            <h:outputText value="#{bean.tooltipContent}"
                rendered="#{bean.tooltipVisible}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:tooltip>
    <p:remoteCommand name="loadTooltip"
        action="#{bean.loadTooltipContent}" update="tooltip-content-wrapper" />
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("[id='form:button']").on("mouseover", function() { loadTooltip(); });
</script>
```

And the backing bean:

```
public class Bean
{
    private boolean tooltipVisible = false;
    private String tooltipContent = "test";

    public void loadTooltipContent()
    {
        tooltipVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I've tested the code and it works here. Note that the bean must be a managed bean.

Comment: ya, inside the datatable i have date as one of the field '<h:outputlabel value = "#{bean.date}"/>'.when mouse move over there i want to show the <p:tooltip> with remaingdays.

Comment: @Arun Then modify the jQuery selector to match your outputlabel. I cannot create a full working ready-made piece of code with the information you supplied. You need to modify the example you match your case.

Answer (score 0):

`<p:toolTip/>` defines javascript events that control it's showing (`showEvent`) and hiding (`hideEvent`) and both default to `mouseover` and `mouseout` respectively. Based on both, you technically could display what you want (preferrably via javascript)

If you're not going the javascript route, you could

1. Define the `title` on your date field and bind to a backing bean variable

   ```
       <h:inputText id="theDate"  value="#{bean.date}" title="#{bean.daysLeft}"/>
   ```
2. Add the tooltip

   ```
        <p:tooltip id="theToolTip" for="theDate"/>
   ```
3. Via an ajax event on the input field , update the title and have it picked up by the tooltip automatically

   ```
        <h:inputText id="theDate"  value="#{bean.date}" title="#{bean.daysLefy}">
           <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.someMethodToUpdateDaysLeft}" update="theDate,theToolTip" execute="theDate"/>
        </h:inputText>
   ```

Comment: While using your procedure i'm getting Exception like "<p:ajax> Event attribute could not be determined: null"

Comment: @Arun, my mistake: `execute` in step 3 should be `process`

Comment: execute on <p:ajax> ?!!